# Which is the proper place to declare gridOptions of ag-grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ag-grid

You can decalre gridOptions propert of ag-grid like 
1.(Inside the component)

```react
const GridComponent:FC = () => { 
   const gridOptions = {}
   <AgGridReact
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        rowData={rowData}
    />        
}
```

OR (Outside the component)
2.

```react
const gridOptions = {}
const GridComponent:FC = () => { 
   <AgGridReact
        gridOptions={gridOptions}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        rowData={rowData}
    />        
}
```

How does it matter ? What are the pros and cons.